# Add a Store Locator plugin on WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, location

I want to add a Store Locator plugin to my WordPress website which will function similar to Starbucks "Find Your Nearest". So, I don't want to add the address for it to find the nearest, I want it to automatically get the actual address of the client. I have tried several, like "Google Maps Pro" etc, but they require to manually enter a detailed address.

Comment: You'll need to use HTML5 Geolocation - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: @NeilKennedy and the how do I incorporate the geolocation data with a plugin. Do you know any plugin who will get the data from the GEO? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used  [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-store-locator/)  a couple of times and worked fine for my workload. it has geolocation support and is free.

Comment: I installed this plugin, but it turns out the Geolocation API doesn't function if your site isn't secured with SSL . thanks anyways